# htaccess 301 redirects with multiple domain RewriteCond and RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, multiple-domains

I'm trying to redirect all pages of an old domain to a page about that domain on a new domain.

I have built countless sites using the first 3 lines of the code below which redirects anything that is not www.mydomain.co.uk to www.mydomain.co.uk.

In the following 4 lines im trying to redirect all the pages of olddomain.co.uk to a single page on my new domain www.currentdomain.co.uk/page-about-olddomain

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.currentdomain\.co\.uk$   [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   http://www.currentdomain.co.uk/$1  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond   %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www\.olddomain\.co\.uk$   [NC]
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   ^olddomain\.co\.uk$   [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$  http://www.currentdomain.co.uk/page-about-olddomain  [R=301,L]
```

### What i want to happen

What i expect to see from the above code is that the page **www.olddomain.co.uk/test-page** would redirect to **www.currentdomain.co.uk/page-about-olddomain**.

### What actually happens

What i actualy see is the page **www.olddomain.co.uk/test-page** redirects to **www.currentdomain.co.uk/test-page**.

I believe this to be a conflict between the 2 sets of RewriteConds

Any help on this would me much appreciated and i'm sure there are other people wanting to do a similar thing.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the first three lines?

Comment: the first 3 lines redirect to www.currentdomain.co.uk if the site is accessed without the www (e.g. http://currentdomain.co.uk) or using an alternate domain (http://www.currentdomain.com)

Comment: Ok, in that case @LazyOne answer should be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by **swapping the order of the rules** thanks to *@LazyOne* and adding the **[OR]** condition after the first RewriteCond that checks for the olddomain with the www's

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.co\.uk$   [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.co\.uk$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.currentdomain.co.uk/olddomain-page [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.currentdomain\.co\.uk$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.currentdomain.co.uk/$1  [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Order of rules matters. Swap them around -- move first rule (lines 1-3) below 2nd.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.currentdomain.co.uk/page-about-olddomain [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.currentdomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.currentdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm afraid this has not worked. I did have the rules this way round to begin with. I just double checked and i get the same result regardless of the order of these 2 rules.

Comment: Then do some debugging -- remove `%{HTTPS}` lines, remove non-www to www rule as well -- possibly (the most likely reason -- I see no other alternatives right now) you made an error in spelling/escaping old domain name, as apparently that rule is skipped as it cannot match domain name.

Comment: I have removed the `HTTPS` lines and also the non-www to ww rule. Please see the code, i have replaced the actual domain names with dummies `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www\.olddomain\.co\.uk$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^olddomain\.co\.uk$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.newdomain.co.uk/olddomain-page  [R=301,L]` But still this produces the same results. Thanks for your help

Comment: OK .. let's see what `%{HTTP_HOST}` has then: 1) remove first rule (from my answer) and alter last one (target URL + flags): `http://www.currentdomain.co.uk/$1?host=%{HTTP_HOST} [R=302,L]` --this should help you to see what value that variable actually has. 2) When testing it -- use new not-used-before URL (or clear all caches and restart browser) as modern browser do cache 301 redirects, so you may simply see OLD cached redirect (which was not even sent to a server) while new rule still would work.

Comment: I have got it working by adding an [OR] condition after the check for the olddomain with the WWW's. Thanks again for your help